# Webkit CSS-hack deprecated?

Tags: css, webkit

I'm using the `@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` hack to specifically address Webkit browsers.

But it doesn't seem to work, does anybody know if this hack is deprecated?

Is there other ways to target Webkit browsers?

**Update:** Not deprecated, I forgot to put an "and" after "screen".

Comment: Better write code that doesn't require hacks.

Comment: What @duri said. But in answer to your question, i dont think so. I have a hack on a website that is still working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following example will show a colored background on `#box` in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox and Opera.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            #box { background: #f0f; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        I'll have a background in Webkit browsers.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If that isn't sufficient, you can have a look at [this article about browser-specific CSS hacks](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/) on [Webmonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/). It includes work-arounds for both Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, and Opera, and the example above.

Comment: OK, so if I write say "-webkit body {background: salmon}" – the background will be salmon-colored, but only in Webkit?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's not how it works. I was referring to the actual `-webkit` prefixed properties. You could use the Safari-specific hacks from the article for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Webkit CSS hack:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            #box { background: #f0f; }
```